# Variable value in Xcode4

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I want to watch variable `[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness`.

So I click rmb in watch window, select Add expression and enter `[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness` as my expression to watch. Xcode evaluates it but does not show the value.

How to watch it properly?

Comment: HA, when I try to make watchpoints, Xcode crashes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can watch a property. You have to watch an instance variable. (Watchpoints actually use hardware support to monitor a memory address for changes. Properties are actually specialized syntax for a method call, and there's no memory address for the result of a method call.)

Since you're trying to watch a property in a system class you might be out of luck. Instead, you might need to write code that adds a KVO observer for the main screen's brightness value, and set a breakpoint in the observer code.

Comment: In VS there is QuickWatch feature if you want to check result of a method call. Is there something similar to QuickWatch in Xcode?